# local: -A: invalid option

Tags: node.js, asdf-vm

I fail to install Node.js with [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) on a fresh macOS (M1 chip). How can I fix this? My environment seems to be very vanilla.

```
$ asdf install nodejs 14.15.4
/Users/stefan/.asdf/plugins/nodejs/bin/../lib/utils.sh: line 35: local: -A: invalid option
local: usage: local name[=value] ...
/Users/stefan/.asdf/plugins/nodejs/bin/../lib/utils.sh: line 51: Fermium: unbound variable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  3490    0  3490    0     0  37934      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 37934
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 10858    0 10858    0     0   106k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  107k
Binary not found for version 14.15.4
```

### Versions

- macOS Big Sur 11.1
- asdf v0.8.0
- Homebrew 2.7.5
- zsh

### Debugging

Line 35 of utils.sh

```
  local -A aliases
```

Line 51 of utils.sh

```
  if [ -z "${aliases[lts]:-}" ]; then
    printf "lts\t%s\n" "$version"
    aliases[lts]="$version"
  fi
```

Comment: Also on a M1 Mac?

Comment: Yes, a new M1 MacBook Air.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`brew install bash`

For more details: https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-nodejs/issues/199